# SQL Server Database Project to alter existing database

Tags: sql-server, version-control, database-project

I have a large legacy database I'm working with and the company would like to make some modifications to it. Most of the modifications would be something like modifying a stored procedure that's used for a report. I'd like to figure out the best way to standardize and document any modifications we make.

One way I'm exploring is using a SQL Server Database Project to organize any update scripts, but I'm not really getting the results I'm looking for. I've tried both importing the entire database as well as using the .dacpac as a reference. Turns out that the original database has some validation issues that VS doesn't like, so it's not making it easy to just change what I want to change and deploy that without having to fix a lot of unrelated reference issues.

What I know will work fine is just controlling everything in some deployment scripts, where I can just run an alter command on an existing procedure and leave it at that. This will at least let me use version control for all changes I make, but it's still a pretty manual process.

Are there any other approaches anybody can recommend?

Comment: Maybe this would be better asked on the dba site.   It's a real stretch to call this a programming question.   Try dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: I believe there is nothing to help you other than manually manage GIT or turtle... Otherwise ask company to buy Redgate tools.

Comment: I would suggest you get your database into source control. Then you simply manage like you manage any code base that is under source control.

Comment: Appreciate all the suggestions.  I'm going to look into some SQL database source control tools, and also check out dba stackexchange

Comment: Red-Gate has a lot of articles on CI/CD lately that are worth reading, but you can also use SSDT. You'll need to work out the validation issues - usually through adding the appropriate DB References. I'd recommend reading up on DBs and DevOps, CI, and CD for more ideas, though. It's a pretty broad topic. If you want help w/ fixing the SSDT issues, post another question with details on that. Getting your whole DB into version control will help in the long run, but won't necessarily be easy.